# why do htaccess RewriteRule redirects site?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following htaccess file

```
redirect 301 /index.php/medical-services/botox.html http://www.mysite.ca/medical-services/toronto-botox.php
redirect 301 /index.php/about-us.html http://www.mysite.ca/about-us/
redirect 301 /index.php/contact-us.html http://www.mysite.ca/contact-us.php
redirect 301 /index.php/contact/name.html http://www.mysite.ca/contact-us.php
redirect 301 /index.php/blog/ http://www.mysite.ca/blog/
#lots of 301 redirects
redirect 301 /glisodin-skin-nutrients.php http://www.mysite.ca/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.ca$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.ca/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^mobile$ /newsite2/mobile/ [L]

RewriteRule    ^$    newsite2/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) newsite2/$1    [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !contests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !administrator
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !shop
RewriteRule ^newsite2/(.*)$ ./newsite2/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !contests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !administrator
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !shop
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newsite2/$1 [QSA,L]  
</IfModule>
```

But when I try to enter lets say to:

http://skinvitality.ca/freebotox/
It redirects to to
http://skinvitality.ca/newsite2/freebotox/

I've tryed with everything and nothing has worked.

Any help will be really apprecciated.

Comment: Empty your browser cache, restart browser and try again.

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
RewriteRule    (.*) newsite2/$1    [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newsite2/$1 [QSA,L]
```

over-writing

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.skinvitality.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I don't get it. Do you mena the first two lines overwrites the third one (on your answer) and redirects. Any idea on the fix. I'm new to htaccess rules.

Comment: what are differences between (RewriteRule    (.*) newsite2/$1    [L] and 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newsite2/$1 [QSA,L]) and (RewriteRule (.*) http://www.skinvitality.ca/$1 [R=301,L]) why similar rules?

Comment: tell me what do you want exactly then I can help you, update your initial post with examples.

Comment: Most of the site is inside newsite2, but there are some folder outside like shop, also there are a lot of 301 rules for diferent scripts.
So the problem is that when I try to access http://skinvitality.ca/freebotox/ it redirectsme to http://skinvitality.ca/newsite2/freebotox/

- I need to force www
- Have rewrite newsite2/ to / because the entire site is there with exceptions.
- Need to fix this so newsite2 doesn't show in the url.
edited the question with full htaccess file.

Comment: ok, just exclude exception within RewriteCond and redirect everything to newsite2, is that what you need?

Comment: No, there are hundreds of folders and files to be exclude by hand, and more are created with time. Will have to change the htaccess file everyday to add new exceptions. And that to the site owner is not an option.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23515/discussion-between-necroside-and-akam-omer)